# Monospace Blackletter Typefaces

Tags: fonts, typefaces, monospace, blackletter

Do you know of any good quality Fraktur monospace typefaces, and if so, are perhaps any of them open-source?

**Background:** I was thinking recently that the the blocky nature of Blackletter typefaces (e.g. Fraktur or Schwabacher, see picture below) might make them particularly well suited for monospace, i.e. the constant width kind of font you commonly see used in computer terminals. The graphic elements make it far easier to have consistently-looking `f`, `l`, and `i` while filling up more of the cell width... In contrast to antiqua-based monospace “sans serif” where what are basically serifs need to be added to these letters.

[image]

**What I found thus far:**

The closest I could find were typewriter typefaces from Germany (see example below), none of which were well digitized, a process which I imagine might be more time-intensive than it appears.
This is one image of a typewriter-blackletter typeface I found, and one user linked to a [digitized version](https://www.dafont.com/f25-blacklettertypewriter.font#:%7E:text=German%20%27Schwabacher%20Fraktur%27%20Typewriter%20Font.%20In%20Germany%20there,special%20ones%2C%20you%20saw%20every%20now%20and%20then.) which however is very low-quality (or high-quality wrt. mimicking the “typewriter” artefacts of the font).

[image]

Comment: I found [this one](https://www.dafont.com/f25-blacklettertypewriter.font#:~:text=German%20%27Schwabacher%20Fraktur%27%20Typewriter%20Font.%20In%20Germany%20there,special%20ones%2C%20you%20saw%20every%20now%20and%20then.) on dafont

Comment: What’s your goal?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft to find a monospace blackletter typeface to try out. The previous comment provides one... but it's very low quality. Basically a rasterized version of the exact font I showed in the second image.

Comment: @TheChymera: But to try out for what? You speak of “well suited” and “modern constraints”, but you never describe what your actual use case is. Do you want to use it for source code, typesetting e-mail addresses, a tattoo, …? These use cases have vastly different constraints.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft it says “suited for the modern constraint of constant width”. That is the constraint, the constant width, also known as monospace.

Comment: Well, that condition is naturally binary: a typeface cannot be well suited for it or not, it is either monospace or not. Also it is obviously fulfilled by the typeface you present (or to be precise, a suitable digitialisation thereof). Still, your question suggests that you care about more than just monospace blackletter, e.g., as you discuss some perceived shortcomings (for some unknown application) of the typeface.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft , well Bill's contribution was an answer rather than just a comment, it would surely be worth an upvote, but yes, it does have significant shortcomings, which are obvious at a glance. The letters are eroded, incomplete, and pixelated. The application would be use in modern terminals. I'll edit the question to hopefully make it more clear.